# В виджете FittedBox BoxFit.fill не работает

Tags: flutter, dart

В виджете **FittedBox** свойство **fit: BoxFit.fill** не работает **ПОЧЕМУ-ТО**. BoxFit.fill должен растягивать дочерний виджет на всю ширину и высоту родительского виджета. Так написано в документации

> Fill the target box by distorting the source's aspect ratio.

Самое интересное, что в версииях Dart, в которых не было **Null-safety** точно такой же код работал нормально.

Но этого не происходит. Для простоты я заменил изображение на закрашенный контейнер. Далее полный код и скриншот.

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: const SafeArea(
     child: MyHomePage(),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Align(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   child: Container(
    width: 200.0,
    height: 200.0,
    color: Colors.amber,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: FittedBox(
     fit: BoxFit.fill,

     /*child: Image.asset(
      //width = 240, height = 400
      'assets/images/a.jpg',
     ),*/

     child: Container(
      width: 240.0,
      height: 400.0,
      color: Colors.green,
     ),

    ),
   ),
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `alignment: Alignment.center` в контейнере явно лишнее, т.к. он у вас уже отцентрирован и похоже оно конфликтует с `FittedBox`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Name App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Name Page'),
        ),
        body: const SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        width: 200.0,
        height: 200.0,
        color: Colors.amber,
        // следующая строка вызывает конфликт разметки
        // alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          child: Container(
            width: 240.0,
            height: 400.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz! Огромное Вам спасибо.